# How did a pawn appear out of thin air in “P @ e2” after queen capture?

Tags: rules, pawns, captures

I was playing chess against the computer and captured black’s queen.  All of a sudden, a black pawn appears out of thin air, one space behind the captured queen for a total of nine pawns, and moves multiple squares diagonally.

[image: board]

The computer calls this move “P @ e6,” but after half an hour of scouring the internet, I could not figure out what that means.

```
1. |  h2 - h4 | Nb8 - c6 |
2. |  e2 - e4 |  e7 - e5 |
3. | Rh1 - h3 | Qd8 × h4 |
4. | Rh3 - h4 |   P @ e2 |
```

How did this happen?

Comment: That first move should be h2-h4, not h2-e4, right?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You were playing the chess variant called [Crazyhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazyhouse). In this variant you can place pieces you captured, as one of your color anywhere on the board, instead of a normal move.

I don't know the software you are using, but on Lichess the variant can be selected in the "Create a game" dialog. There should be something similar in your application.

[image: Lichess]

Comment: Will mark as accepted when I'm allowed to. I wish I knew how to turn that off.

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish I've added some more info, maybe that helps.

Comment: Addition: As you play with a 3D board, what you saw as the pawn moving along the h5-e2 diagonal very likely was just the animation of the "@"-move which coincidentally went over that diagonal.

Comment: Sleafar is totally correct. I'd suggest you play Lichess instead. If I'm not mistaken those at the picture are standard chess for MacOs - they are not that fast and "clever."

Comment: This seems to be the Chess.app that comes with macOS. Also in this one, you choose the chess variant when you create a new game (from the menu, or pressing cmd-N).

Comment: I would add that White has a queen "in hand" (as can be seen on the right hand side of the board), further indicating it is Crazyhouse.

Comment: @Allure That should’ve given it away to me. Good eye.